# Удаление записей (MySQL) от тех авторов, которые их добавили

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите: каждый зарегистрированный пользователь может добавить запись в таблицу, и она выводится на главную, но как организовать так, чтобы только тот пользователь, который добавил запись, мог удалить только её, а просматривать все? Прикрепляю пример удаления пользователя всех записей (использую *RedBeanPHP*)

Index.php

```
<?php
$posts = R::findAll('posts');
foreach ($posts as $post) {
echo $post->id, '<br>';
echo $post->head, '<br>';
echo $post->desc,'<br><br>';
};

<span style="color:green";>ID:</span> <?=$post['id']?><br>
<span style="color:green";>POST:</span> <?=$post['head']?><br>
<span style="color:green";>DESC:</span> <?=$post['desc']?><br>
<a href="delete.php?id=<?=$post['id']?>">Delete</a><br><br>
```

Delete.php

```
<?php

require 'db.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];
$posts = R::load('posts', $id);
R::trash($posts);

echo '<span style="font-size:30px; color:red;";>Success!</span>';

header("refresh: 1; url=index.php");

?>
```

Comment: у каждой записи `post` должно быть поле допустим `ид автора`. Перед тем как удалить запись, сравниваете `ид кто удаляет` и `ид автора`

Comment: Как сделать сравнение, не подскажете?

Comment: оператор условия `IF`

Answer (score 0):

В таблицу `posts` добавить поле `author_id`

Модифицируем файл `Delete.php`

```
require 'db.php';

$author_id = $user_id; // ІД текущего залогиненого пользователя
$id = $_GET['id'];
$exists = R::count('posts', 'author_id = ? AND id = ?', [$author_id, $id]);

if (!$exists) {
    echo '<span style="font-size:30px; color:red;">ERROR! Вы не являетесь автором поста или пост не найден!</span>';
} else {
    $post = R::load('posts', $id);
    R::trash($post);
    echo '<span style="font-size:30px; color:red;">Success!</span>';
}

header("refresh: 1; url=index.php");
```

Также не забудьте записывать при создании `id` автора поста (`author_id`)

Вот вам пример:

```
require 'db.php';

$data = $_POST;

if (isset($data['add'])) {
    $post = R::dispense('posts');

    $post->head = $data['head'];
    $post->desc = $data['desc'];

    $post->author_id = $_SESSION['logged_user']->id;

    R::store($post);

    echo '<p>Успешно!</p>';
}
```

Comment: А скажите еще пожалуйста, как добавить автора поста, вот код:
 <?php 
 require 'db.php';
 $data = $_POST;
 
 if ( isset($data['add']) )
 {
   $post = R::dispense('posts');
   $post->head = $data['head'];
   $post->desc = $data['desc'];
   R::store($post);
   echo '<p>Успешно!</p>';
 }
 ?>

Comment: как вы проверяете зарегистрирован ли пользователь на сайте? где у вас находится информация о залогиненом пользователе?

Comment: <?php if ( isset ($_SESSION['logged_user']) ) : ?> — это проверка зарегистрирован ли пользователь. А вот вывод — Привет, <?php echo $_SESSION['logged_user']->login; ?>

Comment: дописал в ответе

Comment: ID в таблице юзера и post совпадают, вот только автор свой же пост не может удалить..

Comment: Значит вы что-то не так записали. `$_SESSION['logged_user']->id` и `$post->author_id` точно одинаковые?? Проверьте, выведите на экран.